Salesforce Queue Routing: How to implement secondary routing based on the members of the queue
We're using a Queue routing model, and I have a requirement to assign cases to users based on their complexity. More complex cases (determined by specific case attributes) should be routed to more experienced users (based on their attributes).
Once cases are routed to the Queue and placed in the PendingServiceRouting state by Salesforce, I don’t want them to be assigned to agents randomly. Instead, I want to evaluate the case’s complexity, and if it’s high, assign it to an available agent with more experience.
I googled a little and found that SalesForce has feature called External Routing, in which after creating PendingServiceRouting, it won't automatically create AgentWork. My idea is we can create AgentWork manually after PendingServiceRouting trigger, then assign the user manually.
Does anyone have experience on creating custom External Routing, or have other idea to achieve this requirement? Note that we cannot use skill-based routing, we already use Queue-based routing extensively.
